# LayoutParams specific to mobile

Tags: android, gridview, android-layout, imageview

In my application.. Im using 
`imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));`

Now my problem is its not looking good in some mobiles..

How to make this specific to a mobile or according to the resolution i have to change the

`LayoutParams`..

Thanks in advance..

EDIT: Im having a `GridView` and the `SlidingDrawer` in the layout.. The `GridView` is of size 3x3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT or LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT instead of values 85

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using absolute values. If you show us the rest of your layout, or at least tell us what you are trying to do, we may be able to help a bit more.